# Convert plain text to HTML text in Java

Tags: java

I have java program, which will receive plain text from server. The plain text may contain URLs. Is there any Class in Java library to convert plain text to HTML text? Or any other library? If there are not then what is the solution?

Comment: pretty simple to write your own

Comment: Plain text, by definition, can not contain hyperlinks.

Comment: @phihag I'd say this is plain text: "www.google.com"

Comment: You should define your requirements more precisely. What does the plain text look like? What do you expect the resulting HTML to look like?

Comment: Don't be fool. This is pretty simple. atamanroman is right. If i write and save `http://www.google.com` in notepad and save it as text, that is a plain text. And As it contain a hyperlink. And i want to render it in `JEditorPan` as a link. That's all.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneHighlightExample.htm perhaps?

Comment: @user384706 . thats not plain text. that's are html text.

Comment: @Shaiful: strictly speaking `http://www.google.com/` is not a [hyperlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink), it's [an URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). You can easily convert an URI to a hyperlink, if you're working in a format that supports hyperlinks, but plain text doesn't ("a hyperlink (or link) is a reference to a document that the reader can **directly follow**", emphasis mine).

Comment: Upvoting to counter all the downvoting haters on this post. The question is perfectly reasonable if not ideally posed - I know so because I landed here while searching for an answer to the same. The question is basically: is there a public API somewhere that does what the code in Daniel's answer does. Give the OP a break.

Comment: JSoup has a good solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064930/381161

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution using pattern matching. Here is my code -

```
String str = "(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(str);
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(plain);
plain = matcher.replaceAll("<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

And Here are the input and output -

Input text is variable `plain`:

```
some text and then the URL http://www.google.com and then some other text.
```

Output :

```
some text and then the URL <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> and then some other text.
```

Answer (score 35):

You should do some replacements on the text programmatically. Here are some clues:

- All Newlines should be converted to `"<br>\n"` (The \n for better readability of the output).
- All CRs should be dropped (who uses DOS encoding anyway).
- All pairs of spaces should be replaced with `" &nbsp;"`
- Replace "<" with `"&lt;"`
- Replace "&" with `"&amp;"`
- All other characters < 128 should be left as they are.
- All other characters >= 128 should be written as `"&#"+((int)myChar)+";"`, to make them readable in every encoding.
- To autodetect your links, you could either use a regex like `"http://[^ ]+"`, or `"www.[^ ]"` and convert them like **JB Nizet** said. to `"<a href=\""+url+"\">"+url+"</a>"`, but only after having done all the other replacements.

The code to do this looks something like this:

```
public static String escape(String s) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean previousWasASpace = false;
    for( char c : s.toCharArray() ) {
        if( c == ' ' ) {
            if( previousWasASpace ) {
                builder.append("&nbsp;");
                previousWasASpace = false;
                continue;
            }
            previousWasASpace = true;
        } else {
            previousWasASpace = false;
        }
        switch(c) {
            case '<': builder.append("&lt;"); break;
            case '>': builder.append("&gt;"); break;
            case '&': builder.append("&amp;"); break;
            case '"': builder.append("&quot;"); break;
            case '\n': builder.append("<br>"); break;
            // We need Tab support here, because we print StackTraces as HTML
            case '\t': builder.append("&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"); break;  
            default:
                if( c < 128 ) {
                    builder.append(c);
                } else {
                    builder.append("&#").append((int)c).append(";");
                }    
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

However, the link conversion has yet to be added. If someone does it, please update the code.

Comment: Ok. Then I should try my own.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't thought about this simple solution. The state machine was for the inverse case, of converting HTML to plain text, which is a bit more difficult.

Comment: You can skip the "encode chars > 128", if you simply specify the correct encoding in a your HTML.

Comment: Yes, but you also can just skip caring about the encoding.

Comment: good answer- I basically copy pasted it into my code. Surprising that there isn't a public API in one of the utility libs like apache commons for this

Comment: Note that the *escaping* portions of the code above can be performed by calling escapeHtml4 - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Rhubarb: What was the code for? Always nice to know where code I wrote is used :)

Comment: Woow. You saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

Just joined the coded from all answers:

```
private static String txtToHtml(String s) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean previousWasASpace = false;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                if (previousWasASpace) {
                    builder.append("&nbsp;");
                    previousWasASpace = false;
                    continue;
                }
                previousWasASpace = true;
            } else {
                previousWasASpace = false;
            }
            switch (c) {
                case '<':
                    builder.append("&lt;");
                    break;
                case '>':
                    builder.append("&gt;");
                    break;
                case '&':
                    builder.append("&amp;");
                    break;
                case '"':
                    builder.append("&quot;");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    builder.append("<br>");
                    break;
                // We need Tab support here, because we print StackTraces as HTML
                case '\t':
                    builder.append("&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;");
                    break;
                default:
                    builder.append(c);

            }
        }
        String converted = builder.toString();
        String str = "(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(str);
        Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(converted);
        converted = matcher.replaceAll("<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
        return converted;
    }
```

Comment: For URL like `www.stackoverflow.com` should be converted to `http://www.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 4):

Use this

> ```
> public static String stringToHTMLString(String string) {
>     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string.length());
>     // true if last char was blank
>     boolean lastWasBlankChar = false;
>     int len = string.length();
>     char c;
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
>         c = string.charAt(i);
>         if (c == ' ') {
>             // blank gets extra work,
>             // this solves the problem you get if you replace all
>             // blanks with &nbsp;, if you do that you loss 
>             // word breaking
>             if (lastWasBlankChar) {
>                 lastWasBlankChar = false;
>                 sb.append("&nbsp;");
>             } else {
>                 lastWasBlankChar = true;
>                 sb.append(' ');
>             }
>         } else {
>             lastWasBlankChar = false;
>             //
>             // HTML Special Chars
>             if (c == '"')
>                 sb.append("&quot;");
>             else if (c == '&')
>                 sb.append("&amp;");
>             else if (c == '<')
>                 sb.append("&lt;");
>             else if (c == '>')
>                 sb.append("&gt;");
>             else if (c == '\n')
>                 // Handle Newline
>                 sb.append("<br/>");
>             else {
>                 int ci = 0xffff & c;
>                 if (ci < 160)
>                     // nothing special only 7 Bit
>                     sb.append(c);
>                 else {
>                     // Not 7 Bit use the unicode system
>                     sb.append("&#");
>                     sb.append(new Integer(ci).toString());
>                     sb.append(';');
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return sb.toString();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If your plain text **is** a **[URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)** (which is different from **containing** a **[hyperlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)**, as you wrote in your question), then transforming it into a hyperlink in HTML is simply done by

```
String hyperlink = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>";
```

Comment: That's not String. That is total plain text with URL. `some text and then the URL http://www.google.com and then some other text.`

Comment: Actually, if you render that as HTML it will be a link. You should do a bit of reading about HTML.

Comment: @Tanner - Did you mean, if i set the htmltext of JEditorPan to a plain text, then all string start with http://.... will be a link?

Comment: No. Your JEditorPane needs to be set the html. It then will render any text as HTML. That means it will accept and render HTML. <br> <p> etc. For it to display a link you need to format your URL to a link which can be done using the format JB Nizet said. <a href='url'>text</a>

Answer (score 2):

In Android application I just implemented HTMLifying of a content ( see https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/issues/375 ). Actual transformation was done in literary 3 lines of code using Android system libraries. This gives an advantage of using better implementation at each subsequent version of Android libraries.

```
private static String htmlifyPlain(String textIn) {
    SpannableString spannable = SpannableString.valueOf(textIn);
    Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    return Html.toHtml(spannable);
}
```