# Need help modifing regex

Tags: java, regex, url

I am currently using the regex given below to add hrefs to my urls. But recently I got a bug because one of the urls had a full stop after it and the regex added the dot into the link.

```
(?:https?|ftps?)://[\\w/%.-]+", "<a href='$0'target='_blank'> $0</a>
```

So,can it be modfied so that it takes only one dot? I'm using Java.

Comment: Try this :\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])? or this \://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$

Comment: I edited mine like this and it worked.                                 "(?:https?|ftps?)://[\\w.]+/[\\w]+", "<a href='$0'target='_blank'> $0</a> "

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert plain text to HTML text in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134959/convert-plain-text-to-html-text-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

But you can find a lot more [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Answer (score 0):

I edited mine like this and it worked."(?:https?|ftps?)://[\w.]+/[\w]+"