# Text Align in Android Text View

Tags: android, base64, sharedpreferences, textview

I am trying to show base 64 Decode string in the above format in text view But it shows as plain text. If according to my app requirement, we save this decode sting in Shared preference when again rendered this string from shared preference it so well. But this  only show when if my app close and run again.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, graece dicunt his ex, nostrud feugait
>   sapientem ea vis. Noluisse fabellas cum ei? Id mei oblique alterum
>   placerat, alia dicam consetetur eu pri. Eum graeci eirmod no, per
>   facilisi adolescens ut! Sea ex delenit blandit.
>
> - Dolorem appareat sententiae vis te, ad pri errem homero nusquam, primis impedit epicurei vel at? Nonumes delicatissimi per te, ex his
>     nisl nonumy pericula.
> - Cum id deleniti perfecto, ea eos tantas consequat, sea nihil mentitum at? Eos in quod habeo. Ei sea mazim viris similique, te
>     facete evertitur nam.
> - Iisque corpora appellantur sea te. Duo cu percipit adipisci reformidans, congue ridens vel te, sea et fabulas constituam?
>
> No amet deseruisse pro! Semper sanctus copiosae sit ei, id detraxit
>   gubergren vim, an decore fabulas mediocrem sea! Vel graece copiosae
>   moderatius ei? Partiendo dissentias ad duo, eos erat scribentur no. Te
>   cum justo saepe perpetua!
>
> - Cu falli ornatus pri, ei mei efficiendi dissentiet? Cu quo aeque vituperatoribus. Sea ad augue consequuntur, prodesset disputationi ei
>     sea, mei eu nibh latine abhorreant?
> - Tantas qualisque voluptatum ut cum, ornatus tincidunt pro et! Eros elitr sententiae eam id, vel adhuc saperet utroque ut. At aeque
>     debitis nostrum per, aeque menandri ut has, ei cum nostro graecis.
> - Vis ei sumo enim summo, cum ea prima ignota incorrupte, ne est libris oblique docendi!
>
> No officiis facilisi mediocrem mel,
>
> 1. usu lorem ignota oporteat ea, ferri quando no qui. Harum definiebas ut qui, verterem dissentiet eum an
> 2. Id cum tale semper scribentur, et has dicant nominavi luptatum. Te eam primis electram vituperatoribus, ut cum soleat phaedrum!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should save string as HTML and use Html.fromHtml() to show it.
Example:

```
htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>Lorem ipsum...</p><ul><li>Dolorem appareat....</li><li>Cum id deleniti ...</li><li>Iisque corpora appellantur ...?</li></ul><p>No amet deseruisse pro!...</p><ul><li>Cu falli ...</li><li>Tantas qualisque ...</li></ul><p>No officiis...</p><ol><li>usu lorem ignota ...</li><li>Id cum tale ...</li></ol>"));
```

Comment: But String is receiving from server . how to add Html Tag in this String

Comment: You should try to format string as HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134959/convert-plain-text-to-html-text-in-java

Answer (score 0):

**Use it**

```
text1 = text1.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "WRAP");
  text1 = text1.replaceAll("WRAP", "\n\r");
```